# Left Join not working as expected

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

Hi helpful clever people, I am running into an issue when trying to prepare a query. I am trying to join a count of sales and a running total of sales to a prebuilt temp table.

The temp table (TMP_WEEK_SHOP) just has 2 rows, a list of week codes(WEEK_ID) and then an entry with that code for every location(SHOP_ID).

Now my issue is that no matter what i do, my queries will always omit results from the temp table if there were no sales for that location during that week. I need all entries for every week to be entered, even the 0 sales shops.

From what i can gather a left outer join should give me this, but no matter what i have tried it keeps omitting any shops without sales. I should say I am running on an SQL Server 2005 environment with Server Management Studio.

Any help at all would be fantastic!

```
USE CX
SELECT tws.WEEK_ID as Week, isnull(tws.SHOP_ID,0)as Shop, isnull(count(sal.SALES_ITEMS_ID),0)Sales, isnull(sum(sal.LINEVALUE),0)Sales_Value
FROM TMP_WEEK_SHOP tws
JOIN CX_DATES dat
on dat.WEEK_ID=tws.WEEK_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CX_SALES_ITEMS sal
on sal.DATE_ID=dat.DATE_ID
and sal.SHOP_NUM=tws.SHOP_ID
JOIN CX_STYLES sty 
on sal.STY_QUAL = sty.STY_QUAL
WHERE sty.STY_RET_TYPE='BIKES'
and (sal.SHOP_NUM='70006' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70008' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70010' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70018' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70028' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70029' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70012' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70016' or sal.SHOP_NUM='70026')
GROUP BY tws.WEEK_ID, tws.SHOP_ID
ORDER BY tws.WEEK_ID, tws.SHOP_ID
```

Comment: Perhaps try turning dates join into a left join as well

Comment: Sadly not, i have been trying out various join configurations and they seem to be making little to no difference

Comment: Make all joins `LEFT OUTER` and let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query, formatted a bit better so I can read it:

```
SELECT tws.WEEK_ID as Week, isnull(tws.SHOP_ID,0)as Shop,
       isnull(count(sal.SALES_ITEMS_ID),0)Sales, isnull(sum(sal.LINEVALUE),0)Sales_Value
FROM TMP_WEEK_SHOP tws JOIN
     CX_DATES dat
     on dat.WEEK_ID = tws.WEEK_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CX_SALES_ITEMS sal
     on sal.DATE_ID = dat.DATE_ID and
        sal.SHOP_NUM = tws.SHOP_ID JOIN
     CX_STYLES sty 
     on sal.STY_QUAL = sty.STY_QUAL
WHERE sty.STY_RET_TYPE='BIKES' and
      (sal.SHOP_NUM in ('70006', '70008', '70010', '70018', '70028', '70029', '70012', '70016', '70026')
GROUP BY tws.WEEK_ID, tws.SHOP_ID
ORDER BY tws.WEEK_ID, tws.SHOP_ID;
```

You have three problems that are "undoing" the `left outer join`.  The `inner join` condition will fail when `sal.STY_QUAL` is `NULL`.  SImilarly, the `where` conditions have the same problem.

You need for all the joins to be `left outer join`s and to move the `where` conditions to `on` clauses:

```
SELECT tws.WEEK_ID as Week, isnull(tws.SHOP_ID,0)as Shop,
       isnull(count(sal.SALES_ITEMS_ID),0)Sales, isnull(sum(sal.LINEVALUE),0)Sales_Value
FROM TMP_WEEK_SHOP tws JOIN
     CX_DATES dat
     on dat.WEEK_ID = tws.WEEK_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CX_SALES_ITEMS sal
     on sal.DATE_ID = dat.DATE_ID and
        sal.SHOP_NUM = tws.SHOP_ID and
        sal.SHOP_NUM in ('70006', '70008', '70010', '70018', '70028', '70029', '70012', '70016', '70026'
                        ) LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CX_STYLES sty 
     on sal.STY_QUAL = sty.STY_QUAL and
        sty.STY_RET_TYPE='BIKES'
GROUP BY tws.WEEK_ID, tws.SHOP_ID
ORDER BY tws.WEEK_ID, tws.SHOP_ID;
```

In addition, `count()` never returns a `NULL` value, so using `isnull()` or `coalesce()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that seems to have solved the join issue. I'm now getting overly large numbers in my results, but i have a sneaking suspicion that that is more to do with our...odd table layouts.  thanks for the detailed description.

Comment: @Jack . . . Your numbers are probably too big because you are joining along different dimensions and getting cartesian products of rows.  The solution is to pre-aggregate the data along each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

your other join onvolving CX_SALES_ITEMS sal needs to be an left outer join as well